# Magento 1.9 - How to separate translations by Canadian provinces

Tags: php, magento, translation

I'm trying to build a Canadian website in Magento CE 1.9 and I want to separate translations of my website into 4 parts: "English Ontario", "French Ontario", "English Quebec", "French Quebec". Because the phrases will be different. I do not understand how to organize the directories with the translation files "translate.csv" in 
/app/design/frontend/default/(my_theme)/locale/???_???/

The best for me is to have folders like "en_ON", "fr_ON", "en_QC", "fr_QC" but I think that's not possible... Not supported by Zend.

Thank you!

Comment: Does the phrasing actually differ that much by province or are you trying to use the localization system to present targeted content? I suspect you can make custom locales but I'm not sure that would be worth the trouble...

Comment: Yes, it is because the phrases are different in each region.